# Button that takes action and then depending on result changes the View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have found so many articles that are not quite what I am looking to do and I've spent 2 weeks trying to find a solution. I am trying to create a button that has an action. Once said action has completed, then I want to either refresh the current View (in case of error) or send the user to another View if action completed successfully.

Using:

```
NavigationView { 
   VStack { 
      NavigationLink (destination: ItemDetails(blItem:blItem)) { 
         Button { 
            let sendData = "name=\(name)&recordID=\(blItem)" 
            RemoteCenter.post(url: "update.php", params: sendData, completion: self.editItem) 
         } 
         label: { 
            Label("Save Record", systemImage: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

My Completion function is:

```
func editItem(Data: Data?) { 
   isSheetPresented = true 
   guard let actualData = Data else { 
      print("Error (display all data): \(String(describing: Data))") 
      return 
   } 
   
   RemoteCenter.get(url: "get.php?bucketList=true&user=1") { fetchedData in 
      print(fetchedData) 
      bucketList = fetchedData 
   } 
}
```

While this method will send the user to the new View, it does so before taking the button action. If I change it up, placing the View <ItemDetails(blItem: blItem)> inside of the eitItem func and replace the Nav link above with:

```
NavigationView { 
   VStack { 
      NavigationLink { 
         Button { 
           let sendData = "name=\(name)&recordID=\(blItem)" 
           RemoteCenter.post(url: "update.php", params: sendData, completion: self.editItem) 
         } label: { 
           Label("Save Record", systemImage: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill") 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Then I get a message "Result of 'ItemDetails' initializer is unused". This will perform the action and save my changes, but won't trigger the new view. In UIKit, I would have just triggered (or dismissed) a segue, but I'm trying to learn SwiftUI. In this particular case, I want to go back a screen on success.

/* Edit */

Many thanks to@workingdogsupportUkraine. I had tried and failed using NavigationStack previously as I either had a page randomly disappear or my app would simply crash.

After much playing around and going line by line in my code, I was able to resolve my issue with NavigationStack. For anyone else out there having issues with understanding NavigationStack, let me first say to start by reading:
https://medium.com/@mdyamin/navigationstack-revolution-of-nested-navigation-with-swiftui-7a00782b974b.

This will help you to understand the basics. Now in my case, I was still seeing weird issues with crashing or one specific page randomly disappearing off the stack. It came down to 2 lines of code. I had declared:

`@Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL`

Then inside my code I was using a List to display data. One row had a URL and I was it to the user using:

`openURL(url)`

Upon realizing this was breaking the NavigationStack, I removed both of those and updated my code to the following:

`Link(item.url, destination: url)`

The link still works as expected, but more important, so does the NavigationStack. I still need to add an action to one list item that will trigger a database update and then return the user back one level of the stack upon completion, but I'm getting closer everyday to figuring this out.

Comment: Note, a `NavigationLink` is already a `Button`, there is no need for an additional `Button` view (which often creates problems when tapping).
 Remove the `Button` part. Also note, `NavigationView` is deprecated you should use `NavigationStack`. See [navigationstack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/) for info on how to use it.